# I need some advice on learning path

Tags: reactjs, react-native

React Native or React JS, can you please tell me which one I should learn, and yes I know absolutely nothing aside from Colt Steele's web dev Bootcamp(we did have jQuery in that course, is it the same thing). If someone could explain to me the difference between React Native and React-Redux, that would be awesome, and please don't laugh if my question makes no sense. You can ignore it quietly. Thanks
I was asked to edit my question so here it goes, which tutorial will make more sense for a new learner,this one https://www.udemy.com/course/the-complete-react-native-and-redux-course/?ranMID=39197&ranEAID=O*yDCFDQTmY&ranSiteID=O.yDCFDQTmY-pbBV5G_YA1uxwpEcfTPfUg&LSNPUBID=O*yDCFDQTmY or this one https://www.udemy.com/course/react-redux/?ranMID=39197&ranEAID=O*yDCFDQTmY&ranSiteID=O.yDCFDQTmY-pbBV5G_YA1uxwpEcfTPfUg&LSNPUBID=O*yDCFDQTmY

Comment: Please rename your question to something more meaningful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React.js is:

> A JavaScript library for building user interfaces

React Native is:

> A framework for building native apps using React.

Which field of software development to you want to be involved in?
Web development or mobile app development?

Redux is:

> A State Container for JS Apps

So basically you use Redux to manage state in your React app.

Comment: Web development, so I should start with React JS, isn't it? Thanks

Comment: Glad to help you, @SauravSingh. Please mark this question as accepted if it solved your problem so that other people can know it too